# Calendar view using w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar

Tags: javascript, razor

I have a razor macro with a variable "allshifts_name" in Umbraco, and need to show events on the calendar, but I keep getting this error message: "CS1002: ; expected" , but I can't see where it's missing.

`allshifts_name += """ + item.Value("wwdate").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + """ + ": {'number': " + 10 + ", 'badgeClass': 'badge-warning',"url": " + http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar + ", "dayEvents": [{"name": " + "Important meeting" + ","hour": + "17:30" + " },] },";

If I only use this code:
`allshifts += "\"" + item.Value<DateTime>("wwdate").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "\"" + ": {'number': " + 10 + ", 'badgeClass': 'badge-warning'},";`
it's okay, but adding this
`"url": " + http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar + ", "dayEvents": [{"name": " + "Important meeting" + ","hour": + "17:30" + " },]`   it fails.

Can anyone help me out.